# How to search prefix with "-" in aws structured query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with amazon cloud search api. I am using "prefix" operator to search and it's working fine at some level.

**Working Copy:**

```
AWSURL/search?q=
(and    
    (and searchtype:'Event' server:1 ) 
    ( and 
        ( or eventownerid:70 eventcreatedbyuserid:70 ) 
    ) 
    (prefix 'event')
)&size=10&q.parser=structured
```

Non Working / issue

```
AWSURL/search?q=
(and 
    (and searchtype:'Event' server:1 ) 
    ( and 
        ( or eventownerid:70 eventcreatedbyuserid:70 ) 
    ) 
    (prefix 'event-1')
)&size=10&q.parser=structured
```

When I passed search term with "-" it stop giving result.

I have also tried url.Encoded for special charter but no luck with that as well.

1. What to do to include "-" in prefix ?
2. Is there any way where i can search with any part of word in **all
   columns** of document. for example the field contain text "this is
   GreatSearchTech", I want this in result when i pass "Search" as
   search term / word. ?

Thank you in advance.